# Android YouTubePlayer UI customization

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I am using YouTubePlayerFragment from YouTube Android Player API. I want to customize UI. Particularly hide video title at top left and hide YouTube logo at bottom right, but keep all other controls. Is there any way I can do this. MINIMAL and CHROMLESS style is not an option since I want to have seekbar and options menu for this player.

Answer (score 2):

you can't do that using the YouTube Player API. To overcome the issue of limited customization options (among other issues) I've built an opensource player to replace the one from Google. [Android-YouTube-Player](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/Android-YouTube-Player).

To hide part of the UI you can simply do this

```
PlayerUIController uiController = youTubePlayerView.getPlayerUIController();
uiController.showVideoTitle(false);
uiController.showYouTubeButton(false);
```

You can customize the UI even further, the library has an API to replace the default UI with whatever View you want.

`View customPlayerUI = YouTubePlayerView.inflateCustomPlayerUI(R.layout.custom_player_ui);`

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/Android-YouTube-Player/wiki/Replace-the-player%27s-UI).

Comment: Your player is working via Iframe. We also played Youtube vidoes in Iframe. The issue with that, is some videos not played, due to author disallow playing them outside of youtube site. Is your player having same issues?

Comment: the Iframe player is provided by Google, therefore there's no differences from the Player API in terms of being outside of YouTube. It's an official API.

I never had issues with videos not playing in players external to the YouTube website. But I guess if issues of this kind exists they must exist for every player provided by Google.

Comment: For example this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=va9mGwngAfM is not playing in Iframe, but playing via Youtube SDK player

Comment: Just tried with my player: it works for me. Maybe there's some country restriction?

Comment: I remembered one extra thing that we used in our iframe implementation. For some specific reason(which I can't recal) we replaced UserAgent from Android to empty `userAgent.replace("Android", "")` I think this is the reason of difference with your implementation